# Duplicates With Different Answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, answer-quality, unaccepted-answer

In my professional career there have been countless times that I've dealt with the issue, can I `reinterpret_cast` an [`XMFLOAT3`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xmfloat3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or a similar struct, to a `float*` and treat it like an array of 3 floats.

I've asked a detailed question about it here: [Casting a Struct to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29277949/2642059) and accepted [Jonathan Wakely's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29278260/2642059) which says that **yes this is legal**. The answer is well sourced, and as I accepted it, I obviously feel well defended. [MSalters also provides an unsourced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29278638/2642059) which says **no this isn't legal**.

Unfortunately, this question has been marked as a duplicate to these questions:

1. [A question about casting in C *or* C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9747010/2642059) and the answer given says **yes it is legal** but only references the C spec and a C++ proposal so I'd consider the documentation extremely lacking at best
2. [What seems to be in fact a C++ duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9747010/2642059) with an accepted answer which seems inferior to Jonathan Wakely's answer on my question, but this accepted answer says **no this isn't legal**
3. Lastly **2** is duplicated to [this language lawyer question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31082389/2642059) which doesn't have an accepted answer; [its most up voted answer is unsourced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082498/2642059) but claims **no this isn't legal** there is [an additional answer which is sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082764/2642059) but also claims **no this isn't legal**

And well at this point I'm confused and disappointed in the system we have setup. We struggle in that there *isn't consensus*, the answers are distributed across defunct questions.
I recognize that I'm part of the problem here, I've asked a duplicate of a question that was already here, but had unsatisfactory answers. So now I've gotten what appears to be the best answer, but now it lives on a duplicate question.

---

I'm presenting this issue to say that it's hard when a question that I need a good answer to has already been asked, but doesn't have a good/well sourced/accepted answer. My duplication of this question was wrong... but it produced the best result so far: A well sourced accepted answer.

I'd like to ask 2 things:

1. **Is there a way to point users to better answers even if they are on duplicate questions?**
2. **Is there a mechanic for reactivating a question? Somehow, making old questions appear new with the potential of a new answer being accepted?**

Comment: 1. yes; reverse the duplicate closure. If your question has the better answer then other questions should be pointing towards it.

Comment: There's also question merging, which is a rarely-performed moderator-only task that I'm not sure would be appropriate in this case. And, of course, the answerer could simply answer the duplicate target with their better answer.

Comment: You appear to think that accepted answers are more important than they are.  They're just one person's opinion on the usefulness of an answer.  Not having an accepted answer on a question is not a problem, changing an accepted answer is not necessary just because you like a different answer more, etc.

Comment: I am not a C++ expert but I would be surprised for it to be OK because it might *not* be OK on C due to possible range checking, the cast to `float *` would be considered as a cast to pointer to the first element of the struct which is as if an array of one element... but again, I am not a C++ expert...

Comment: The first duplicate is incorrect anyway - the reinterpretation to the first element is explicitly allowed by both languages and it is undisputed, what could be disputed is whether you are allowed to access the successive members of the struct given a pointer to the first.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm presenting this issue to say that it's hard when a question that I need a good answer to has already been asked, but doesn't have a good/well sourced/accepted answer.

The appropriate course of action for attracting additional answers to a question you feel needs more information is a bounty, not intentionally asking duplicates until you're satisfied with the answers you get.

Comment: That's probably correct, but for the sake of argument and for the much more common case, can we assume that OP didn't know about the duplicate when asking the question? We stumble upon such cases all the time where the 2017 version of the question has a much better answer than the 2011 version of it, right?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The question in general, and in particular the quote in my answer, suggest that's not the case here.  Given that they're so concerned with explaining how they don't like the answers on the duplicates, rather than how they couldn't find them.

Comment: But.. but.. you're losing rep to creating bounty and not gain extra reps by making new questions. Joke aside, that's probably resulting in so many duplicates today.